# SubStage fails on generating code for an SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, subsonic, substage

I use SubStage to generate classes for an SQLite DB. On pressing "Test connection" it throws:

> Connection Failed: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.60.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Can anyone tell what is going on? .NET data provide for SQLite dll is persent in the same directory as SubStage exe file.

Comment: Ok the troubles was that I run it on x64 and I needed x64 SQLite.Data version...
So guys be very attentive!!!